# Bitwise Operations using Elasticsearch NEST Api

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Are bitwise operations supported using the NEST API in ElasticSearch?

There is no documentation for NEST and I can't find any information on this, nor have we been able to guess at possible syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Bit wise operations can only be performed using [scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/7.x/painless-operators-numeric.html#bitwise-and-operator)
ex

```
"script" : {
                "inline": "def x = 15 & 6;", 
            }
        }
```

Outside of scripts there is no specific bitwise query. Check this open request  for the same https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/975